# Как подписать приложение своим ключом на Андроиде?

Tags: android

Мне нужно подписать приложение своим же ключом на телефоне Андроиде. Ключ я брал из андроид студии. Какие приложения для этого есть, именно на андроиде?

Comment: Один только вопрос, зачем? В голове только одна мысль, что ты сломал чье-то приложение.

Comment: Свое приложение, надо подписать своим же ключем. Доступа к студии пока что нет, а приложение сделано через конструктор, который не даёт ключей.

Comment: Ну тогда [вот](https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=211229)

Comment: Ключ у меня свой, там нельзя выбрать именно свой

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать через командную строку:

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name

Или так:

$ keytool -export -rfc
  -keystore your-upload-keystore.jks
  -alias upload-alias
  -file output_upload_certificate.pem

Полная инструкция:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#signapp

Answer (score 0):

Можешь воспользоваться таким приложением, как ApkEditor, в маркете оно по другому называется (если не удалили), качай с интернета